# Insert blank line in UNIX after different number of lines

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a file abc.csv with below data:

```
abc
def
geh
ijk
lmn
opq
rst
```

Now, I want to insert blank lines after line2 and line 6.

Please suggest which command shall I use.

Comment: What have you tried? I only see one line int hat file - is that all one line, or is it multiple lines and you simply did not format the question correctly?

Comment: Does line numbers (where blank ones needs to be inserted) always stay the same? For every file? You must be more clear on that point. What you are asking is possible with awk, sed, perl, bash, etc...

Answer (score 12):

```
$ seq 10 | sed '2G;6G'
1
2

3
4
5
6

7
8
9
10
```

The `G` `sed` command appends a newline followed by the content of the hold space (here empty as we don't put anything in it) to the pattern space. So it's a quick way to add an empty line below that matched line.

Other alternatives are the `a` and `s` command:

```
sed '2a\

6a\
'
```

Or:

```
sed '2s/$/\
/
6s/$/\
/'
```

Some `sed` implementation also support:

```
sed '2s/$/\n/;6s/$/\n/'
```

Comment: What is the Posix way to do it? Related, why does a simple insert not work? I.e., `sed -e '3i ' somefile > somefile.new`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '2a\ ' -e '6a\ ' input > output && mv output input
```

Some sed(1) flavours have an `-i` option to operate on a file "in-place" (but that is not portable), or try `sponge` from moreutils, but both of those methods are merely hiding the write-to-new-file-and-`rename(2)`-system-call that the `mv` does (if the output file is on the same filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
awk 'NR==3||NR==7 {print " "} {print $0}' abc.csv > temporary.csv && mv temporary.csv abc.csv
```

Comment: I want to save the changes in the file. How will that be done?

Comment: @NikhilSinha I modified the answer and now the changes go to the original file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '6pu_|2pu_|x' abc.csv
```

1. `pu_` append blank line
2. `x` save and close

Comment: Portably, you would need to avoid the black hole register as it's Vim specific.  Instead use the `a`ppend command: `printf %s\\n 6a '' . 2a '' . x | ex abc.csv`